# Who sets date/time automatically from the hardware clock at boot?

Tags: linux, boot, date, time, clock

When Linux is booting, the current time must be fetched from a RTC chip and then set to Linux system date/time. I can do this manually by running `hwclock --hctosys`. But where exactly does this happen automatically at boot time? Is there a process taking care of this? Does the kernel do this job?

Comment: This is done by udev when `/dev/rtc` shows up: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b6e44cd934873659f233bfd962e4a0dcb3026e59/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules.in#L9-L11

Comment: @HenriMenke that just creates the `/dev/rtc` symlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1: Linux Kernel loads time from RTC chip

One can set `CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS` in kernel config to enable this feature. When enabled, the Linux Kernel will take care of reading stored time in `rtc0` and setting it to system time. With `CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS_DEVICE="rtc0"` the device can be altered.

For this to work the according RTC driver must be compiled as built-in module.

### Method 2: udev calls hwclock as soon as /dev/rtcX is created

The package `util-linux` provides a udev rule file at `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules` which can be copied to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. The udev daemon will then call `/usr/lib/udev/hwclock-set` automatically as soon as /dev/rtc0 is created. You can change `rtc0` in `85-hwclock.rules` if needed.

Comment: `hwclock-set` script has a condition for ".../system" folder. When it does exist, the script exits, leaving the clock intact.

Comment: That folder is being created early (much earlier than udev starts) so that script is useless. Moreover, commenting out that condition, will cause access denied errors on "hwclock" calls (when the script is called by udev). So it seems totally useless.